# Bash - Run 3rd script after previous 2 are complete

Tags: bash, background-process

I have the following bash script that runs 3 php scripts in order and only starts the next script once the previous one is complete:

```
#!/bin/bash
php -f one.php &&
php -f two.php &&
php -f three.php
```

However, one.php and two.php don't rely on each other and it would be faster if they ran simultaneously.  Is it possible to do the following?

```
run one.php and two.php
once one.php and two.php are complete, run three.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put 2 processes in background, wait for them and then run third one:

```sh
php -f one.php &
php -f two.php &
wait
php -f three.php
```